# Working with variable dimension tensors in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, variable-length-array, ragged

I want to build a tensor placeholder, features with dimension, say `(10, a, a)`. Such that `features[i, :, :]` can be an arbitrary square tensor. As an instance, `features[0. :, :]` may be of dimension `5*5`, and `features[1, :, :]` can be of dimension `8*8` at the same time. How can we do this with tensorflow?
I found ragged tensors for this purpose. But the problem is that for feeding values in the ragged tensor, I will have to use normal lists in python. In my case this feed list is very sparse and there is no way to compress ragged lists.

Comment: Can you provide a example? How are you storing your data out of TensorFlow in the first place?

Comment: @jdehesa I have data in the form list of list of list.